# Nokia Here v3: How to put text in standard marker?

Tags: here-api

It was very easy to put text in `StandardMarker` in previous Nokia HERE API (v2). In new API (v3) I can't find solution how to put text in marker. Here's a code snippet:

```
var coords = { lat: 56 lng: 54 };
marker = new H.map.Marker(coords);
map.addObject(marker);
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the standard icon doesn't support text. But you could try the approach used in the dev guide (https://developer.here.com/javascript-apis/documentation/v3/maps/topics/markers.html) by creating an icon from SVG.

Answer (score 2):

I also recently faced this problem. I reverse-engineered the HEREMaps JS API `core` module and made a **marker with text** SVG markup template out of it.

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="28px" height="36px">
    <path d="M 19 31 C 19 32.7 16.3 34 13 34 C 9.7 34 7 32.7 7 31 C 7 29.3 9.7 28 13 28 C 16.3 28 19 29.3 19 31 Z" fill="#000" fill-opacity=".2"/>
    <path d="M 13 0 C 9.5 0 6.3 1.3 3.8 3.8 C 1.4 7.8 0 9.4 0 12.8 C 0 16.3 1.4 19.5 3.8 21.9 L 13 31 L 22.2 21.9 C 24.6 19.5 25.9 16.3 25.9 12.8 C 25.9 9.4 24.6 6.1 22.1 3.8 C 19.7 1.3 16.5 0 13 0 Z" fill="#fff"/>
    <path d="M 13 2.2 C 6 2.2 2.3 7.2 2.1 12.8 C 2.1 16.1 3.1 18.4 5.2 20.5 L 13 28.2 L 20.8 20.5 C 22.9 18.4 23.8 16.2 23.8 12.8 C 23.6 7.07 20 2.2 13 2.2 Z" fill="#18d"/>
    <text x="13" y="19" font-size="12pt" font-weight="bold" text-anchor="middle" fill="#fff">${text}</text>
</svg>
```

Working code snippet [here](http://jsfiddle.net/glenn/ez9tr66k/).