# Configuring HERE Javascript Maps v3 to use miles by default

Tags: javascript, here-api

Apparently, by default HERE Maps use the metric measurement.

You can switch to miles manually by clicking on a [scalebar](https://developer.here.com/javascript-apis/documentation/v3/maps/topics/map-controls.html):

[image: here map using kilometers]

So after clicking it looks like the following:

[image: here map switched to miles]

The locale in use is `en-US`:

```
ui.getControl('scalebar').getLocalization()
```

How do I set the map to use the imperial measurement units by default, on map load?

**UPDATE** I looked through the map's HTML code and the `ui.getControl('scalebar')` methods and properties before posting, searched the Internet, found nothing.

**UPDATE** Here's a working [**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/glenn/ez9tr66k/) taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30698931/722036), it has the necessary map code and the API keys. As you can see, it loads to kilometers, and when you click the scalebar it switches to miles.

Comment: Don't make us hand type your markup for testing. You copy it here.

Comment: You need to supply a minimal, reproducible section of code that shows the problem. Images are not acceptable.

Comment: @Rob [official documentation minimal example](https://developer.here.com/javascript-apis/documentation/v3/maps/topics/quick-start.html#basic-scenario-code-complete), [jsfiddle showing the same issue](http://jsfiddle.net/glenn/ez9tr66k/). Please let me know if you think I should add something else to my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
ui.setUnitSystem('imperial');
```

I modified your fiddle here:
https://jsfiddle.net/won5uqr7/1/

Relevant documentation:
https://developer.here.com/javascript-apis/documentation/v3/maps/topics_api_nlp/h-ui-ui.html#h-ui-ui__setunitsystem

Comment: Wow, so simple, yet so hard to find. It worked, thank you so much @Mark!